# Sparse Protractor

Tags: code-golf, math, number-theory, geometry, abstract-algebra

Given some positive integer `n`, design a protractor with the fewest number of marks that lets you measure all angles that are an integral multiple of `2π/n` (each in a single measurement).

#### Details

As an output, you may output a list of integers in the range `0` to `n-1` (or `1` to `n`) that represent the position of each mark. Alternatively you can output a string/list of length `n` with a `#` at the position of each mark and a `_` (underscore) where there is none. (Or two different characters if more convenient.) 
**Example:** For `n = 5` you need exactly 3 marks to be able to measure all angles `2π/5, 4π/5, 6π/5, 8π/5, 2π` by setting (for example) one mark at `0`, one mark at `2π/5` and one mark at `6π/5`. We can encode this as a list `[0,1,3]` or as a string `##_#_`.

[image]

#### Examples

Note that the outputs are not necessarily unique.

```
n:  output:
 1  [0]
 2  [0,1]
 3  [0,1]
 4  [0,1,2]
 5  [0,1,2]
 6  [0,1,3]
 7  [0,1,3]
 8  [0,1,2,4]
 9  [0,1,3,4]
10  [0,1,3,6]
11  [0,1,3,8]
20  [0,1,2,3,6,10]
```

PS: This is similar to the [sparse ruler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_ruler) problem, but instead of a linear scale (with two ends) we consider a circular (angular) scale.

PPS: This script should compute one example of a set of marks for each `n`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVJNb6MwEL37V8wh0toKoNDeqiSHVdVT9xcg1BhigoU9RrbZ7Vb97@kY0jbtag9Y@L2Z9@bDvQyDMuZ81nZ0PsK9jLJ41CGya@BhwjZqh4xJY@6JBQQTYAeBQlY4NRVwmTcCDtYdD0S@goRtTjEZNMtPDXkOJ4XKy6iAZGB0IejGKDiSoMRWBei8s3DSvxWC9F7iSVmFkbG2dy4o0h3Ic7n8gM18/69qmJqgIrgOjMJT7CmW/mNPDMHVJiuzm@w2K4oiw7ysGfzplVfsQ/5pln@lczvbVvU1t6GPsKr@gib8O9peyq6gvTOkZ9I83knerksBnAoQfKCjhvWawH9ZGARj1Gun8QgSQT1LO1KX1JLVqK00gJNtlJ8R6QcapvO0hWWayC4Jv2YK0@pIaLUkT/bnXzJzdpRewcHhAfgytIKihKC4TptI4pzvdiiKC9mFmDha/nM2ewrqb0j9VWVRYA3ZFbPNOf98PdvVXuz3uxc9JoXP/daMWalTfaPXGInj/EvpKREoE3hn9AhJQMx25WZ@Ym6K4xQDTY3MF2txPr8B)

PPPS: As @ngn pointed out, this problem is equivalent to finding a minimal difference base of a cyclic group of order `n`. The minimal orders are listed in http://oeis.org/A283297 and some theoretical bounds are found in https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.02631.pdf

Comment: [Related.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/149137/8478)

Comment: [Borderline dupe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/108044/194), with exact overlap when `n = q^2 + q + 1` for prime power `q`.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I don't see why you think it is a dupe. And can you elaborate in what way there is an "overlap"?  Even though there are similarities, these are two very different problems. Furthermore this is [tag:code-golf] and challenge you linked doesn't even include the size of the program in its scoring.

Comment: They're not two very different problems. Read the OEIS link in your PPPS: the "difference set of Singer" referred to there is precisely the Golomb ruler generated by the projective field method implemented in my answer. I take the point that the scoring method is different.

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 20 bytes

```
:qGZ^!"G:q@&-G\m?@u.
```

This runs out of memory on TIO for inputs beyond `8`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/36rQPSpOUcndqtBBTdc9JtfeoVTv/38LAA)

#### How it works

This generates the Cartesian power of `[0 1 ... n-1]` with exponent `n`, and uses a loop to test each Cartesian tuple. The test consists in computing all pairwise differences of element if the tuple, and seeing if those differences modulo `n` include *all* numbers `0`, `1`, ..., `n-1`.

As soon as a Cartesian tuple fulfilling the condition is found the loop is exited, and the *unique* entries in that tuple are printed as the solution.

This works because given ***u*** > ***v***, a *sufficient set* of tuples with ***u*** *unique* entries are guaranteed to be tested *earlier* than any tuple with ***v*** unique entries. A "sufficient set" means that if none of the tuples in that set are a solution then no other tuple with the same number of unique entries is a solution.

For example, for `n = 3` the Cartesian tuples are as shown below, where each row is a tuple:

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 2
0 2 0
 ···
2 2 1
2 2 2
```

- The first tuple, `0 0 0`, is the only relevant tuple with `1` unique value. Even if `1 1 1` and `2 2 2` will appear much later, `0 0 0` is a solution if and only if those are. So the singleton set formed by the tuple `0 0 0` is a sufficient set for ***u*** = `1`.
- The second and third tuples, namely `0 0 1`and `0 0 2`, form a sufficient set for ***u*** = `2`; that is, they cover all cases with `2` unique values. The fourth tuple, `0 1 0`, will never be selected as solution, because `0 0 1` will have been tested first. Similarly, the tuple `0 2 0` will never be selected because it appears later than `0 0 2`. Tuples such as `2 2 1` will never be selected as solution because the `0 0 1` is equivalent (modulo `n` and up to duplicated values) and appears first.
- Etc.

Commented code:

```
:q         % Push [0 1 ... n-1], where n is the input (implicit)
GZ^        % Cartesian power with exponent n. Gives an (n^n) × n matrix
           % where each row is a Cartesian tuple
!          % Transpose. Now each Cartesian tuple is a column
!"         % For each column (that is, each Cartesian tuple)
  G:q      %   Push [0 1 ... n-1] (*)
  @        %   Push current column
  &-       %   Matrix of pairwise differences (**)
  G\       %   Modulo n, element-wise
  m        %   Ismember function: for each entry in (*), gives true iff
           %   it is present in (**)
  ?        %   If all entries are true
    @      %     Push current column
    u      %     Unique entries. This is the solution
    .      %     Break loop
           %   End (implicit)
           % End (implicit)
           % Display (implicit)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
ŒPðṗ2I%QLðÐṀḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//xZJQw7DhuZcySSVRTMOww5DhuYDhuKL/MTFSwrU7IsOH4oKsR/8)

#### How it works

```
ŒPðṗ2I%QLðÐṀḢ  Main link. Argument: n (integer)

ŒP             Powerset; generate all subsequences of [1, ..., n].
  ð       ÐṀ   Begin a dyadic chain. Call it with all subsequences S as left
               argument and n as right one. Return the array of all sequences for
               which the chain returns the maximal result, i.e., [0, ..., n-1].
   ṗ2              Cartesian power 2; generate all pairs of elements of S.
     I             Increments; map each pair [x, y] to [y-x].
      %            Map each [y-x] to [(y-x)%n].
       Q           Unique; deduplicate the array of modular difference singletons.
        L          Take the length.
         ð     Begin a new, dyadic chain.
               Left argument: S' (filted subsequences). Right argument: n
            Ḣ  Take the first element of S'.
               Since S was sorted by length, so is S', so the first element of S'
               is the shortest subsequence that satisfies the condition.
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>26</s> 21 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
Åæ4&╕u◙╩►s∙Φ▬═(0~ d+Q
```

[Run and debug online!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=%C3%85%C3%A64%26%E2%95%95u%E2%97%99%E2%95%A9%E2%96%BAs%E2%88%99%CE%A6%E2%96%AC%E2%95%90%280%7E+d%2BQ&i=1%0A2%0A3%0A4%0A5%0A6%0A7%0A8%0A9%0A10%0A11%0A&a=1&m=2)

<s>Right now the online version fails for input `20` but this bug has been fixed and is yet to be deployed to the online interpreter</s>  Deployed. Beware it takes some time to run the `20` case.

### Explanation

Turns out that due to way pairwise difference is calculated, I don't need to worry about the equivalence of `k` and `x-k` here. Saving 5 bytes.

Uses the unpacked version to explain.

```
rS{%o~{;i@c:2{E-x%mu%x<wm
r                            [0..`x`], where `x` is input
 S                           Powerset
  {%o~                       Sort by length
      {;i@             w     For each element in the powerset
          c:2                All pairs
             {    m          Map each pair `[p,q] to
              E-                 `q-p`
                x%               `(q-p)%x`
                   u%        Count of unique modulo differences
                     x<      Loop until the count of unique modulo differences is larger than the input(`n`)
                             Now we have found a valid set in the powerset
                        m    Output the members of the set,one element per line.
```

By enforcing the requirement that `0` and `1` both be members of the answer, we can generate the powerset with `[2..x]` instead of `[0..x]` and then add the `0` and `1` manually to every element in the powerset. It is more efficient but need to handle the input `1` specially and costs more bytes.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
_þ¹F%³³Ḷ¤ḟ
ŒPÇÐḟḢ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##AS0A0v9qZWxsef//X8O@wrlGJcKzwrPhuLbCpOG4nwrFklDDh8OQ4bif4bii////MTA)

-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder

Comment: You don't need the leading `R`.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder oh right, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 148 bytes

```python
from itertools import*
def f(n):
 r=range(n)
 for i in r:
  for p in combinations(r,i+1):
   if all(any((y+x)%n in p for y in p)for x in r):return p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY2xDsMgDER3vsJLJWhYEqlLpH4MbaG1FGzkuFL4ehpYut3z@e5K1Q/T0loSzoAaRZm3HTAXFr2aV0yQLLnVgNwl0DueYCCxAAISyGkMKp2enB9IQZFpt@JxmnsQABOEbbOBqrV1OtyF@ncZwTqk6/IYjW6VqF85j@0/M5Znv9x6YREkBfTJoms/)